# Is it possible to connect to mssql with windows auth mode from a nodejs app running on linux?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, linux

I'm trying to connect to a mssql with Windows authentication mode (can't change that) from nodejs running on a linux machine.
I tried many things, all of them resulted in nearly the same error, here is an attempt using tedious with this simple code running on a linux machine with nodejs:

```
let tedious = require('tedious');
let Connection = tedious.Connection;
const config = {
    userName: 'myUserName', 
    password: 'myPassword', 
    server: 'MyServ',
    options: {
        database: 'MyDbName'
    }
}

function handleConnection(err: any) {
    if (err) console.error("error connecting :-(", err);
    else console.log("successfully connected!!")
}

let connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', handleConnection);
```

I get this error

```
error connecting :-( { ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''. 
at ConnectionError (./node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12) 
at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on.token (./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:848:51) 
at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13) 
at Parser.parser.on.token (./node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:37:14) 
at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13) 
at addChunk (./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:298:12) 
at readableAddChunk (./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:280:11) 
at Parser.Readable.push (./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:241:10) 
at Parser.Transform.push (./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:139:32) 
at doneParsing (./node_modules/tedious/lib/token/stream-parser.js:122:14) message: 'Login failed for user \'\'.', code: 'ELOGIN' }
```

The credentials I used do have SQL rights (tested with ODBC on windows machine).
Am I doing something wrong or is it just impossible ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how Windows Authentication works in SQL Server. When you use Windows Authentication, you don't supply a username or password explicitly, instead it automatically picks up the credentials from the context of the user account under which the code is running. Clearly, this requires you to be running under a Windows account which is in the same Active Directory domain as (or a domain trusted by) the SQL Server. So unless your Linux machine is joined to an AD domain and you are running under an AD account, it cannot work.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it easy? No. You would be better off asking on the Ubuntu/Linux communities (depends what distribution you're using) on how the configure kerberos on unix environments if you must use a trusted connection.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connect has a simple intro example (using sqlcmd, but the concept is the same no matter what client code is being used).

Comment: If it *were* only that simple, @ADyson :)

Comment: It is possible - https://sequelize.org/ id rock solid.

Comment: @Nelles that's just an ORM code library. It does not, of itself, allow Windows Authentication. It might _support_ it, but it's not a solution on its own. As I explained in my first comment, the context in which the code is running is the important thing.

Comment: Anyway, if it's not possible for you to connect from a domain-joined Linux machine, then your options are either a) run your code on Windows, or b) use SQL authentication to connect to the DB.

Comment: After some work and many tries I'm able to connect to my DB from my linux machine using the command line 
`tsql -S servNameOnFreeTdsConf -U "domain\userName" -P password`
with freeTDS and ODBC installed and configured.
Still no luck with my nodejs app though.
The fact that I succeed to connect from my linux machine should suggest that my machine and account are joined to the AD of the server like @ADyson suggested right ?

Comment: Anyway https://www.freetds.org/userguide/domains.htm says "When neither option [SSPI or Kerberos] is enabled, FreeTDS can still log in using the domain account, but the user must supply the username & password". But this is not the same as Trusted Authentication which is what will be expected by the SQL libraries underlying your nodeJS code. In those libraries, when you specify a username and password, it expects them to be a SQL login, not Windows. FreeTDS is not used for that.

Comment: So no, specifying a domain user and password by hand from FreeTDS does not indicate anything about the status of your Linux machine on the Active Directory domain. All it indicates is that you succeeded in using this specific technique which happens to be supported by FreeTDS, but not by the general SQL Server client libraries.

Comment: P.S separately to that, I noticed the error is specifcally `Login failed for user ''` - i.e. an empty string. And I also noticed that in all the examples at https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql, the configuration object has `user` as the property rather than `userName`. So that won't be helping - the error right now is that it doesn't even know what user you want to connect as. For all that my info above about windows auth is relevant, in actual fact your code hasn't even got as far as worrying about that yet.

Comment: However if you wanted (and were able) to use domain login, then as per https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#configuration-1 I think you are supposed to set the `domain` option rather than supplying user and password, so that it picks up the current domain user's credentials automatically. However as an experiment you _could_ try setting `user: "DOMAIN\username"` and the password, and see what happens. My suspicion is it wouldn't work, but worth a go, I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ADyson thank you a lot for your informations, you managed to pinpoint the solution to my poorly formulated problem caused by my total lack of knowledge on the subject, really thank you again. the solution was to use domain login this snippet worked :

```
const config = {
    user: MyUserName,
    password: MyPassword,
    server: 'MyServAdress',
    database: 'MyDbName,
    domain: 'MyDomain'
}

const sql = require('mssql');
sql.connect(config).then((pool: any) => {
    console.log('connected!');
}).catch((err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: If this is your answer, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, it's possible to receive data form a linux client using windows authentication only enabled. MS SQL Server and NodeJS Linux Server are in the same network. The linux Server isn't domain-joined:

[image]

I used this to run execute my query:

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const config = {
  server: 'SERVER',
  database: 'DATABASE',
  user: 'USER',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  domain: 'DOMAIN',
  options: {
    enableArithAbort: true // required, otherwise deprecation warning
  }
}
  
sql.connect(config)
  .then((conn) => {
    console.log('MSSQL: connected');
    conn.query(`SELECT ..`)
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .then(() => conn.close())
  }).catch(err => { console.log(err) });
```